# Python Pandas dataframe performance : range selection vs dual condition in indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to find the most efficient way to do range selection in a pandas dataframe on a String index (In my real world use case, those are dates that I have converted to string : would it be faster with pandas Datetime ?)

Setup

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
import time as t
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(
"col,value\n\
a,1\n\
b,2\n\
c,3\n\
d,1\n\
e,2\n\
f,3\n\
g,1\n\
h,2\n\
i,3\n\
j,1\n\
k,2\n\
l,3\n\
m,1\n\
n,2\n\
p,3"
))
df.index = df['col']
num_runs=1000
```

And the 3 tests :

```py
# solution 1
start = t.process_time()
for i in range(0,num_runs):
    df.loc["a":"j"]
end = t.process_time()
print(f"1: {1e4*(end-start)/num_runs:.2f}m")
#solution 2
start = t.process_time()
for i in range(0,num_runs):
    df[(df.index >= "a")& (df.index <= "j" )]
end = t.process_time()
print(f"2: {1e4*(end-start)/num_runs:.2f}m")
#solution 3
start = t.process_time()
for i in range(0,num_runs):
    df[(df["col"] >= "a") & (df["col"] <= "j")]
end = t.process_time()
print(f"3: {1e4*(end-start)/num_runs:.2f}m")
```

The output is :

```
1: 1.56m
2: 5.00m
3: 8.75m
```

I understand why 3 is much slower than the other 2 but I'm not sure I understand why 1 and 2 are that much different.

Any python/pandas guru to shed some light ?
Also if there is an even more efficient way I'm all ears of course.

Comment: On a side note - when doing timings - use the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module instead of writing your own approach.

Comment: I know ! :) I can never get it to work. Feel free to show how you would have done it in that case...

Comment: I'd have thought that leaving them as DateTime or making sure they're effectively a [`DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html]) would be best... even more so if you make sure it's sorted into index order... then it can do binary searching/other tricks to efficiently access your range (don't have time to test anything at the moment though)

Comment: Yes that was my hunch as well - will test it properly. The question still stands though (strings or datetimes)

Comment: Well, in general, if they're actual datetimes - have 'em as datetimes as you'd then get all the extra stuff you can do with them if needed... I wouldn't have thought a DatetimeIndex would be less efficient than a string, and even if it was slightly, the overhead of the to/fro conversion would most likely swamp it anyway...

Comment: One thing that might be worth trying to see if it affects (1) is if you shuffle the index so that `df.index.is_monotonic` is false - I'll take a punt that the slice syntax there is optimised for the true case and more effective because it can use a binary search to isolate the range rather than two full scans to find the start/end indices... so when that optimisation isn't available - it effectively has to fall back to your case (2) or(3) (or something else). If that is indeed the case - then the datatype isn't even relevant here